# How to prevent rendering of SSRS report through URL access

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I'm looking for a way to prevent the rendering of a SSRS report, while accessing it through URL access method.

I have report A, through while I drillthrough to another report (Report B) using URL access method, using a set of parameters.

Now I'm looking to prevent the rendering of report B (while is the default behavior it seems)  i.e. as soon as user clicks on relevant field on report A, report B opens up with relevant parameters selected as passed through URL access but without the report being rendered, so as to give end user more flexibility if he/she wants to change the parameters of report B in some way.

I have removed the below code from URL access, however this is the default behavior of the report, so the report renders anyway.

```
&rs:command=render
```

Also, tried something like below. Didn't work.

```
&rs:command=norender
```

Would appreciate any pointers here, to get this done.

Regards.

Comment: It seems you are linking to the report server url which is going to render the report (that’s what it was designed to do). Perhaps you can instead like to the Report Manager URL? Not sure what type of control you will have over the parameters though.

Comment: Thanks for the tip thomas. Will try this and get back.